# Photo Sharing from iTunes

Tags: itunes, photos, home-sharing

In iTunes, from the Advanced menu, I selected Photos to Share.  I then picked a folder and the hard drive cranked at full speed for good 5-10 minutes.

I do not see any of the photos on the iPad.  So, who did I actually share the Photos with?

Comment: can you add screen shots of the steps you took, I think you may have missed something along the way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mathias is [correct](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/45148/11791) about the proper way to **sync** photos to your iPad. **Sharing** photos from iTunes approves them for *Home Sharing*, a system designed to share iTunes Store purchases and media amongst family members.

Apple Knowledgebase: [iTunes: Setting up Home Sharing on your computer](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4620)

Home Sharing can also be used to allow access to photos from an AppleTV.

Apple Knowledgebase: [Setting up Home Sharing for Apple TV (2nd generation)](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4352)

Comment: So just that I have this right.  I can share video and audio from iTunes to the iPad (without having to sync or take up space on the iPad), but not Photos?

Comment: So long as you're on a shared network you can access songs or videos in a Mac's (and maybe a PC's) iTune's Library using the iPad. Photos aren't stored in the iTunes Library and while you can Home Share for access from an AppleTV (2g), I don't believe they're any mechanism for doing the same on an iPad, iPhone or iPod Touch.

Answer (score 3):

You don't copy Photos to an iPad using the Advanced menu…

Here’s how I do it: go to iTunes → Devices → Your iOS Device → Photos → enable “Sync Photos from…” and choose either iPhoto album(s) or a folder on your hard drive. Then press the Sync button in the bottom right corner.

See Apple Knowledgebase: [iOS and iPod: Syncing photos using iTunes](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4236) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that **Advanced > Choose Photos to Share** uses iTunes' [Home Sharing feature](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3819) to share photos with [Apple TV devices](http://www.apple.com/appletv/).

[image]

If you want to sync photos from your computer to the iPad, you can either use [PhotoStream](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4486) or enable photo syncing when you connect the iPad.